# Freemarker how to access next element in sequence

Tags: java, freemarker

My code -

```
 <#list elements as element> 
   //how can i do something like
   ${elements[element_index + 1]}
  </#list>
```

The above code doesnt compile.

I need to access the next element in sequence.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want just skip first element in list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to get an item out of `element`, but element is already the item out of `elements`. In this case, `elements` has to be a sequence, from which you can get items, so your code should look like

```
<#list elements as element>
    <#if element_index < elements?size-1>
        ${elements[element_index + 1]}
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Keep in mind, that this won't work once you reach the last item in `elements`! There will be some kind of `OutOfRange` error.

Comment: Sorry for the typo just updated my code  I am getting `Expression elements[element_index + 1] is undefined`

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: Have you tried the code again? I added the brackets and the dollar sign around the expression

Comment: That is same as my code mate and i mentioned the error already

Comment: Anyone has come across this before?

Comment: @OpenSourceRulzz I updated the code again, the error was just the thing i wrote at the bottom of my reply, saying that there will be some OutOfRange error. That was exactly the case here, so you need the extra if to prevent that.

Comment: @OpenSourceRulzz Is your question answered by that or still problems?